# Use LESS stylesheets in VS2017 Angular 5 project

Tags: angular, webpack, less-loader

I believe it should be easier than it looks. I'm new to webpack and I spent hours trying to figure out what I'm missing.

All I need is to add LESS preprocessor to `webpack.config.js`. Rule for CSS is already there and it works:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] }
        ]
    }
```

But once added very basic rule for less-loader, like `{ test: /\.less$/, use: 'less-loader' }` (I've tried numerous variations of this rule), I always get an error `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type` on my LESS stylesheet. Really? I'm providing the loader, what else it needs?

I'm trying to use my stylesheet in Angular component like so:

```
@Component({
    styles: [require('./my.component.less')]
})
```

Exact error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module 
parse failed: Unexpected token (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
// few lines of my styleshhet, so it was indeed located properly
// call stack ... at Object.module.exports ... at __webpack_require__...
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it fully working. It took hours and I haven't found everything in one place, so I'm posting full answer here.

**TL;DR**
This is working configuration in `webpack.config.js`, use it in `sharedConfig.module.rules` collection:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/, use: [
    { loader: "to-string-loader" },
    { loader: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' },
    {
         loader: "less-loader",
         options: {
             fallback: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'
         }
     }]
}
```

Gotchas here:

1. Trying to use it in client bundle configuration, I got "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" on prerendering
2. Trying to use it without fallback option, I got "window is not defined" on prerendering
3. You need all three loaders in line, otherwise also doesn't work
4. I believe minification will work as expected, however have not tested yet.